# Best way to define composite primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would a create a users table with id primary key, name, password. I want all the names within the users table to be unique.
Which is the best way to do it.

1. Define (id, name) as a composite primary key.
2. Define (id) -> primary key and name -> unique key.

Why would you choose one over other?

Comment: Remember that *if* you have a composite key (made up from multiple columns), then all tables that want to reference that table using a foreign key relationship will **also** need **all** those columns from the composite primary key - you cannot reference just "half" a PK - it's all or nothing

Comment: If you want the names to be unique then it would be a mistake to have a composite key because that wouldn't enforce the uniqueness of name. Make id and name two separate keys. It makes no difference which of them you designate as "primary key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best" way, although a lot of people will try to tell you there is.

You can use an artificial key, like your id field, which is usually an integer, or a natural key, which would be your name field.

Which one you choose is mostly personal preference.  There are pros and cons to each, but successful applications have been built with both.  Do a search for "artificial vs natural key" to find countless debates about which is best.

However, there would be no point to creating an ID field, and then making a composite primary key - use either the ID field alone, and create a unique index on the name, or use the name field and don't bother with an id.

Comment: I agree with both statements made here. First, there's no universal "best" way, it all comes down to what you need to achieve. Second statement is inferred - the first option from the question was reduced from composite key to using a natural key (name) instead of artificial one (id). In my opinion, composite key (id, name) won't bring you anything compared to just (name).